# Using external fingerprint scanner to login to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint

I have Dell XPS 15 L502X, 2011 edition.

I also have a fingerprint scanner [Nitgen Fingkey Hamster HFDU01](https://www.bayometric.com/nitgen-fingerprint-reader-fingkey-hamster-i-dx/).

I have installed biometric scanner drivers and ran the its diagnostic utility, in which I am able to capture the fingerprint.

I want to use this device for Windows login. Can I do that?

I just checked my settings and it says "Windows Hello isnt supported on this device." Also it does not show button for adding fingerprints.

I am running Windows 10 Home, version1803, OS build 17134.345.

[image]

I read online. There are [articles](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/windows-hello-isnt-available-on-this-device-on-windows-10-solved/) asking to use gpedit to enable Windows Hello. But Windows 10 Home doesnt come with gpedit. So I added gpedit following [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/access-group-policy-editor-even-windows-home-settings-try/) article. But now I realize that I dont have "Biometric" entry under "Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components":

[image]

Is their any way to use this fingerprint scanner for login to Windows on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Hello has [specific requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/windows-hello-biometric-requirements) for fingerprint readers:

Fingerprint reader requirements

Large Area sensors (a sensor matrix of 160 x160 Pixels or more at a dpi of 320 or greater):

FAR < 0.001%.

Effective, real world FRR with antispoofing or liveness detection <10%.
presentation attack defense measures are a requirement.

Small Area sensors (a sensor matrix of less than 160x160 at a dpi of 320 or greater):

FAR < 0.002%.

Effective, real world FRR with antispoofing or liveness detection <10%.
Presentation attack defense measures are a requirement.

Swipe sensors:

FAR < 0.002%.

Effective, real world FRR with antispoofing or liveness detection <10%.
Antispoofing measures are a requirement.

The drivers require a special Windows Hello signature from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Hello not working issue has appeared after the Windows 10 Creators Update
under many forms and error messages. I resume below most of the known remedies.

**Enable Biometric in Local Group Policy**

Some crucial system settings like the Local Group Policy could be modified during the upgrading of Windows 10 Creators Update which breaks the face recognition and fingerprint reader’s feature of Windows Hello. To exclude that likelihood, you should check the biometric settings in Local Group Policy.

1. Run the Local Group Policy (`gpedit.msc`).
   For Windows Home see
   [How to Access the Group Policy Editor, Even in Windows Home](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/access-group-policy-editor-even-windows-home-settings-try/).
2. Go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Biometrics.
3. Double-click the item "Allow the use of biometrics setting", tick Enabled and OK.
4. Do the same to the item "Allow users to log on using biometrics".
5. Reboot.

If the above steps were not enough, do this :

1. Repeat steps 1 & 2
2. Click on "Facial Features" and double-click "Configure enhanced anti-spoofing".
3. Set it to Disabled and OK.
4. Reboot.

**Reset Facial Recognition and/or Fingerprint Options**

- Go to PC Settings > Accounts > Sign-In options.
- Locate "Fingerprint" or "Facial Recognition" and click "Remove" under them.
- Choose "Get Started" and follow on-screen instructions to reset Fingerprint and Facial Recognition.
- Reboot

**Update Webcam/Fingerprint Driver**

- In Device Manager, locate and expand the entries for the biometrics device.
- Right-click the device and choose "Uninstall".
- In the Action menu select "Scan for hardware changes",
  and let Windows detect and update the drivers.

For more detailed information with screenshots, see the article
[How to Fix Windows Hello Not Working after Windows 10 Creators Update](https://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/window-hello-not-working-windows-10-creators-update.html).

Comment: Have you even read my question completely? I believe I have already tried all things you specified. **(1)** For example, The option `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Biometrics` is simply not there in my gpedit. I have attached screenshot in main question and asked for the same. **(2)** Also fingerprint section doesnt simply appear in my Sign in options windows. Again I have attached the screenshot. **(3)** My drivers must be ok as I am able to test them through diagnostics tool.

Comment: So you have done all this. Dell hasn't posted any new drivers for your model since 2014. For Nitgen drivers, which ones did you install? Have you looked at [these](https://www.bayometric.com/fingerprint-sensor-driver/) as described [here](https://www.bayometric.com/nitgen-fingerprint-scanner-driver/)?

Comment: Yup drivers are working fine, I believe, as in diagnostics utility installed, I can capture my fingerprints. I have installed first drivers in Nitgen category from first link in your comment, titled "Driver ( v3.12 (Windows 32 bit & 64 bit))". (I visited those two links earlier while searching correct drivers for Windows 10. The ones I got in CD only works on Windows 7.) Does Dell have to do anything with this? I feel its Windows thing - not finding those entries in gpedit and Sign in options. Any more idea / suggestions?

Comment: Seems like the drivers you got lack some capability that allows their use for the purpose of login. My only idea left is to get another fingerprint device that is known to support it. Sorry, from my side it seems you did everything right, and it's hardware/software that lets you down.

Comment: Just last try. Is [this](https://www.bayometric.com/windows-biometric-framework/) related? This page talks about Hamster fingerprint scanner and Windows Hello. I tried this but somehow it is not working. But still want to know if the device is officially supported for Windows Hello or not, so that if its indeed supported I will fiddle out more. But I am unable to conclude about official Windows Hello support after reading that article. Is it really about my fingerprint device? Or some other Hamster they are talking about. Also what is connection between bayometric and Nitgen?

Comment: The same website as in your link has a better [article](https://www.bayometric.com/nitgen-fingerprint-scanner-driver/) with a link for downloading drivers, although nothing is said about Hello support. The [Nitgen download page](http://www.nitgen.com/eng/cs_center/public/pds_public_03.asp) only has drivers from 2013, so I don't know if it's still useful. There is [another article](https://kb.swivelsecure.com/w/index.php/Biometric_Fingerprint_for_Windows_Credential_Provider) worth studying where Nitgen/Hamster is said to support Hello, and this one is very recent.

Comment: About the first link, this is what I referred while installing driver and testing with diagnostics tool. About the last link which you linked, looks like third party credential provider called swivel. Is it?

Comment: Looks like it, but as I don't have your environment I don't know if it's any good. The one conclusion we have is that your drivers alone are not acceptable for Hello, so you need to search for software solutions (or hardware ones, meaning getting a better-accepted key).

Comment: Thanks for all inputs. Just some final thought, I feel the issue is both. The fingerprint scanner I have is really very old and it is very must possible that it does not support Windows Hello directly and I may have to try third party solution as you pointed out. But I feel my Windows 10 is equally screwed. Not able to see Fingerprint entry in Sign in options and not finding biometrics entry in gpedit feels weird.

Comment: The Sign in option is not displayed if there's no compatible scanner detected, so I'm not assuming a problem with Windows.